# Atheros AR9285 bluetooth dual mode not working on lubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, bluetooth

My problem is that I have a AR9285 bluetooth + wifi card in a HP probook 4330s. I tried several methods from the internet, still not working the bluetooth dual mode.

- Enabling the btcoex=1

Main symptomps: first after boot the bluetooth.service is in halt state. After restart I can start the bluetooth manager. But When I open, I can't connect to any devices and it drops there is no bluetooth adapters.

here is the outputs.

`uname -a`:

`Linux nolex-dev 4.10.0-35-generic #39~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 13 09:02:42 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`lsusb -t`:

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=, 12M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

`lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 77824  0
bnep                   20480  2
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             200704  0
ppdev                  20480  0
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
kvm                   593920  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
pcbc                   16384  0
aesni_intel           167936  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
arc4                   16384  2
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
intel_cstate           20480  0
uvcvideo               90112  0
ath9k                 147456  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
ath9k_hw              466944  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
snd_hda_codec_idt      57344  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_idt
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
ath                    28672  3 ath9k_hw,ath9k,ath9k_common
snd_hda_intel          36864  3
videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic
mac80211              782336  1 ath9k
joydev                 20480  0
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic
videodev              172032  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
input_leds             16384  0
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
serio_raw              16384  0
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
snd_pcm               102400  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
bluetooth             557056  14 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
lpc_ich                24576  0
cfg80211              602112  4 mac80211,ath9k,ath,ath9k_common
jmb38x_ms              20480  0
snd_timer              32768  1 snd_pcm
memstick               16384  1 jmb38x_ms
snd                    77824  14 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
shpchp                 36864  0
mei_me                 40960  0
mei                   102400  1 mei_me
hp_accel               28672  0
lis3lv02d              20480  1 hp_accel
parport_pc             32768  0
mac_hid                16384  0
parport                49152  2 parport_pc,ppdev
input_polldev          16384  1 lis3lv02d
autofs4                40960  2
hid_logitech_hidpp     28672  0
hid_logitech_dj        20480  0
usbhid                 53248  0
hid                   118784  4 usbhid,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
amdkfd                139264  1
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdkfd
i915                 1449984  3
radeon               1507328  1
psmouse               139264  0
ahci                   36864  1
libahci                32768  1 ahci
r8169                  81920  0
ttm                    98304  1 radeon
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 radeon,i915
mii                    16384  1 r8169
drm_kms_helper        151552  2 radeon,i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sdhci_pci              28672  0
drm                   352256  7 radeon,i915,ttm,drm_kms_helper
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_pci
wmi                    16384  1 hp_wmi
video                  40960  1 i915
fjes                   77824  0
```

`cat /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf`:

```
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1
options ath9k ps_enable=1
options ath9k blink=1
options ath9k btcoex_enable=1
```

`rfkill list`:

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -E 'Blue|ath'`:

```
25:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [103c:1461]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
26:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 03f0:311d Hewlett-Packard Atheros AR9285 Malbec Bluetooth Adapter
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b230 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated HP HD Webcam
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    9.025384] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    9.025402] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    9.025405] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    9.025408] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    9.025413] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    9.213639] ath: phy0: Disabling ASPM since BTCOEX is enabled
[    9.213642] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x60
[    9.213643] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    9.213645] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    9.213646] ath: Regpair used: 0x60
[    9.265926] ath9k 0000:25:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[   14.703648] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   14.703650] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   14.703654] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

`hcitool dev` doesn't drop any kind of adapters. When I plug a custom BT adapter, drops back a device handler for this.

In my opinion the correct device descriptor is missing from the ath9k driver.

**EDIT1:**

Removed ath9k.conf

I tried:

```
modprobe -rfv ath9k
modprobe ath9k btcoex_enable=1
[  300.117260] ath: phy0: Disabling ASPM since BTCOEX is enabled
[  300.117262] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x60
[  300.117263] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[  300.117264] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[  300.117264] ath: Regpair used: 0x60
[  300.118861] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[  300.120210] ieee80211 phy0: Atheros AR9285 Rev:2 mem=0xffffade802450000, irq=19
[  300.120827] ath9k 0000:25:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
```

Adapter not found, same results.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -E 'Blue|ath'` terminal command.

Comment: And what is the current kernel version and the version where it works. I don't see any difference in the code. And also try to delete `ath9k.conf`

Comment: Okay so I tried on ubuntu 14.04.05 LTS, not working with the wifi as well.

Comment: 14.04.5 has the same kernel as 16.04. I suggest reporting a bug to Launchpad by `ubuntu-bug linux`.

Comment: Thanks, you can follow the bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe/+bug/1718010

Comment: Can you edit to include `modprobe -c | grep -i 311d; cat /proc/cmdline`

Answer (score 2):

Okay as pilot6 said I tried to load ath3k kernel module. Now it works well!
Both wifi and audio sink.

```
sudo modprobe ath3k
```

`dmesg` answer:

```
[ 3747.157360] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[ 3747.209334] usb 2-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 3747.575194] usb 2-1.6: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 3747.684269] usb 2-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=311d
[ 3747.684276] usb 2-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 3747.977303] usb 2-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 3748.711212] usb 2-1.6: new full-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 3748.820028] usb 2-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3005
[ 3748.820033] usb 2-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
```

for permanent solution, I had to edit `/etc/modules` and added `ath3k`.

Comment: The question is why `ath3k` was not loading. Is it blacklisted somewhere?

Comment: No results from this command:
sudo grep -rl "ath3k" /etc/modprobe.d/

So it isn't blacklisted.

Comment: What about `grep ath /etc/modprobe.d/*`

Comment: `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf:# which ath5k cannot recover. To prevent this condition, stop`

`/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf:blacklist ath_pci`

Comment: This is not relevant. Try to add `ath3k` to `/etc/modules`

Comment: Had this problem on Xubuntu 16.04. Adding `ath3k` to `/etc/modules` worked indeed. Thanks to both of you.